# Voronoi Diagram: Displaying site specific color in a Voronoi diagram

Tags: plotting, graphics, computational-geometry

I am using Voronoi polygonization as a support for simulating island erosion; my data is the output of `VoronoiDiagram`, `DelaunayTriangulation`, the starting point and the list of points that now are sea. I am not working with `BoundedDiagram` so I made sure all unbounded polygons are at sea.

Now I need to show this output like in `DiagramPlot`, but with sea cells colored blue, and land cells colored in brown.
Can you give me some code example or indications on where to search?

More generally, I need to have a planar graph of which I know vertex coordinates and the edges, what function should I use to choose the color for the faces of the graph?

Comment: Please post a sample of what you already have.

Comment: To shorten the sample you can use `RandomReal` to generate a set of points.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/CreateAVoronoiDiagram.html  Or this? http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagrams/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is just a flow of consciousness... I think you are talking about something like this:

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`

data = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 14.9}, 
       {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 5.1}, 
       {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7}, {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 3.1}, {11, 1.1}};

ubd = DiagramPlot[data, LabelPoints -> False]
```

[image]

So here I think what you want to do:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[Brown], EdgeForm[White], 
  Polygon[Select[vorvert[[#]] & /@ vorval[[All, 2]], 
    Cases[#, _Ray] == {} &]]}, Background -> Blue]
```

[image]

On the other hand image processing does it too:

```
MatrixPlot[MorphologicalComponents[ubd // Binarize] /. {1 -> Blue, 0 -> White, 
   x_Integer /; (x =!= 1) -> Brown}, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

but the payoff is that you lost information about Graphics primitives and went to rasterized images, - which may be fine if you care about visual only.

If you'd figure out how to sea-land with BoundedDiagram-type diagrams, then it maybe easier, because there is another way to make Voronoi. For example here coloring only approximately circular core of Voronoi cells:

```
plt = ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[1, {500, 3}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0];
plg = Cases[plt, Polygon[{x__}] :> x, ∞];
cplg = Select[plg, 
   EuclideanDistance[Mean[plt[[1, 1]][[#]]], 
      Mean[plt[[1, 1]]]] < .3 &];
Graphics[{
   GraphicsComplex[
   plt[[1, 1]], {FaceForm[Blue], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[plg]}],
  GraphicsComplex[
   plt[[1, 1]], {FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[White], Polygon[cplg]}]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you could define `plg = Cases[plt, Polygon[{x__}] :> x, ∞]` (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, much better, updated, thanks ;)

Comment: :-) -- by the way, what is the benefit of keeping the `GraphicsComplex` form here?  Since the points must be resolved for `EuclideanDistance` anyway it seems to me it would be simpler to use coordinates directly.

Comment: You might consider using `Nearest` as belisarius did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32925/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am catching a plane today, but I will have to revisit this after - thanks!

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov, did you have any chance to revisit it? :)

Answer (score 10):

Well, another solution using **V10** functionality:

> ```
> data = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 
>     14.9}, {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 
>     5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7}, {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 
>     3.1}, {11, 1.1}};
> ```

The Voronoi diagram:

```
vor = VoronoiMesh[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We get the `Polygon`s that make up the Voronoi diagram and select the unbounded ones which will represent the sea, while the bounded ones will represent the land. The unbounded polygons must have at least one point in their `RegionBounds` identical to the overall `RegionBounds` of the Voronoi diagram.

```
cells = Map[MeshCoordinates[vor][[#]] &, MeshCells[vor, 2], {2}];
```

**EDIT**
A much easier way to do the above is:

```
cells = MeshPrimitives[vor, 2]; (* I knew there was a better way *)
```

The region bounds of the Voronoi diagram is obtained simply as

```
RegionBounds[vor]
```

> {{-2.7, 17.1}, {-2.4375, 18.7875}}

Using the new `IntersectingQ` we can see which polygons are unbounded/bounded:

```
bound = IntersectingQ[Flatten@RegionBounds[vor], Flatten@RegionBounds[#]] & /@ cells;
```

Now we can plot the regions:

```
polys = Transpose[{bound, cells}] /. {True -> Blue, False -> Brown};

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{White}], polys, Yellow, Point[data]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nicely compact solution, which exploits the fact that the "sea cells" are precisely the cells that contain the points of the data set's convex hull. Another key ingredient is the use of the undocumented function `` Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[] `` (previously presented by ilian [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109687)).

```
data = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 14.9}, {13.2, 11.9},
        {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7},
        {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 3.1}, {11, 1.1}};

vor = VoronoiMesh[data];
ci = Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[vor];
pos = Rest /@ ci[MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[data]]];
cells = MeshPrimitives[vor, 2];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], {{Blue, Extract[cells, pos]}, {Brown, Delete[cells, pos]}},
          Yellow, Point[data]}]
```

[image: Voronoi sea and land]

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 
    14.9}, {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 
    5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7}, {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 
    3.1}, {11, 1.1}};
```

---

Since **v10** there's [`HighlightMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightMesh.html) which allows to highlight the interior and boundary cells in an automated manner (see also [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134625/boundary-cells-of-a-mesh) for some further details about its undocumented features). Let

```
vor = VoronoiMesh[data];
```

Then with

```
h = MeshCellIndex[vor, {2, "Interior"}]
```

> {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 12}, {2, 14}, {2, 16}}

and

```
b = MeshCellIndex[vor, {2, "Frontier"}]
```

> {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 10}, {2, 11}, {2,
>      13}, {2, 15}}

one can do

```
highl = HighlightMesh[vor, {Style[h, Brown], Style[b, Blue]}]
```

[image]

Or also with the cell centroids:

```
pts = PropertyValue[{vor, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];
Show[highl, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

---

Also, if the concern is only about the image, for fun:

```
points = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}];

regBounds = RegionBoundary @ ConvexHullMesh @ data;

f[{x_, y_}] := If[RegionMember[regBounds, {x, y}], 1, -1]
c = ListContourPlot[Function[{x, y}, {x, y, f[{x, y}]}] @@@ data, 
     Mesh -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Frame -> False,
     PlotRange -> RegionBounds @ vor];

plot = Show[
  c /. (Rule @@@ Transpose@{Cases[c, _RGBColor, Infinity], {Brown, Blue}}), 
  points]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
MeshRegion[vor, MeshCellStyle -> {{2,_}->Yellow, {2,"Frontier"} -> Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MeshRegion[vor, MeshCellStyle -> {{2,_}->Yellow, {2,"Interior"} -> Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]