# Quickly selecting for points in a set that are within a critical distance of points in another set

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine two lists of two-dimensional coordinates:

```
listA = RandomReal[{0,100},{202,2}];
listB = RandomReal[{0,100},{97,2}];
```

I'm attempting to quickly generate a new series of lists, `outputListA` and `outputListB` consisting of the indices for the set of points in `listA` and `listB`, respectively, that are within some Euclidean distance $D$ of a point in a list for which they are not a member (i.e. points in `listA` that are at most a distance `distCut` from at least one point in `listB` and vice versa).

This isn't the right way to do things (it takes $\approx 88$ milliseconds for sizes of `listA` and `listB` shown), but it hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
listA = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {202, 2}];
listB = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {97, 2}];

outputList = {};
distCut = 1;

For[x = 1, x <= Length[listA], x++,
 For[y = 1, y <= Length[listB], y++,
   If[EuclideanDistance[listA[[x]], listB[[y]]] <= distCut,
     outputList = Append[outputList, {x, y}];
     ];
   ];
 ];

outputListA = Intersection[outputList[[All, 1]], outputList[[All, 1]]];
outputListB = Intersection[outputList[[All, 2]], outputList[[All, 2]]];

Length[outputListA]
Length[outputListB]
```

A smarter way to proceed might be to round values in `listA` and `listB` to a multiple of `distCut`, and then check for values in the rounded lists that are equal.  However, I can't think of a good way to do this that avoids unnecessary attrition / misses points.

A thought - Can we repeatedly apply `Nearest` for each point $p_i$ in `listA` until we find a point that is more than a distance `distCut` from $p_i$?  Is `Nearest` doing anything more sophisticated than sequentially scanning through all of the points in a comparison list and checking Euclidean distances?

Update - I've specified now that `outputListA` and `outputListB` should consist of the indices of the points in `listA` and `listB` satisfying the distance cutoff criterion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Nearest[]`supports the following syntax:

> Nearest[data,x,{n,r}]  give up to the n nearest elements to x within a radius r

So:

```
listA = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {202, 2}];
listB = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {97, 2}];
distCut = 1;
f = Nearest[listB];
Timing[s = Union[f[#, {Infinity, distCut}] & /@ listA]]
```

> {0., {{}, {{1.80442, 77.5901}}, {{5.51155, 53.6578}}, {{9.51508, 
>       16.3514}}, {{31.804, 24.5855}}, {{35.4298, 36.839}}, {{65.3657, 
>       85.783}}, {{76.6778, 92.0471}}, {{84.3255, 77.5874}}}}

```
Manipulate[
 (s = Flatten[Union[f[#, {Infinity, distCut}] & /@ listA], 1]; 
  Show[ListPlot[{listA, listB}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}], 
       ListPlot[s, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], RGBColor[0, distCut/10, 0]}]]),
    {distCut, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific, any idea what Nearest is doing?

Comment: @RM1618 No, I have no idea about how it is implemented internally.

Comment: Interesting. The `r` here is undocumented `Nearest[data,x,{n,r}]`.

Comment: @Murta I didn't see it either when I looked through the documentation.

Comment: @Murta http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingNearest.html

Comment: @belisarius Ah, very good.  It's just not in the documentation for my Mathematica v9 install.

Comment: @belisarius Exactly. Another interesting point is that `Nearest` creates an index when used as a function. It's not documented too. Time do not growth lineary when points number increase. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @Murta Ah, that explains the non-linear scaling with the point set size I was observing.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this.  I believe I first saw it used by Daniel Lichtblau here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207446/618728

Comment: +1. This is certainly going to be useful to me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've learned it from that answer, but I forgot that :). What a shame.