# measure minimum distance of dots from edge

Tags: image-processing, image

I want to measure minimal distance of small dots from the edge of an image:

Image of bright dots:

[image]

Edge image

[image]

ImageAdd looks like following:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickly selecting for points in a set that are within a critical distance of points in another set](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32923/quickly-selecting-for-points-in-a-set-that-are-within-a-critical-distance-of-poi)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an answer that's based on image manipulation rather than list manipulation. Name the two images

```
dots=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKNn4.png"];
edges=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jbie.png"];
```

Find the components and visualize

```
components = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[Dilation[edges, 1]]];
Colorize@components
```

[image]

We're looking for the exterior of the figure

```
mask = Image[1 - Sign[Abs[ImageData[Image[components]] - 2.]]]
```

[image]

The idea is to take the `DistanceTransform` and then find the point with the smallest distance transform from the edge. This can be visualized as

```
ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform[mask]
```

[image]

Now the product of the dots image times the distanceTransformed image gives pixel values that are the distances from the object:

```
Min[ImageData[dots] ImageData[DistanceTransform[mask]] /. {0. -> 100}]
3.
```

The smallest of these that is nonzero is the smallest distance. So the closest of the dots is three away from the nearest pixel on the edge image.

Comment: I voted to close this one, now I am ashamed. Good one +1

Comment: @belisarius -- the `DistanceTransform` is useful in a surprising number of situations.

Comment: @bills  If you compare the image of dots with above multiplication, then both looks same. Does the list of distances from above multiplication are the distance of each dots?

Comment: The values you find in the distance transform are the distances between *every* point and the boundary of the object. By doing the matrix multiplication, we zero out everything that isn't one of the points of interest (i.e., the dots). So the min over all the values that occur where the dots are is the min you are looking for. The 0.->100 is just to remove all the interior points from the min.