# Site - Cell Correspondence in Voronoi Diagram obtained via VoronoiMesh

Tags: computational-geometry

Consider the following:

```
pts = RandomReal[4, {10, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}];

Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[
   MeshCoordinates[vor], {Thick, Blue, MeshCells[vor, 1], 
    PointSize[0.02], Red, MeshCells[vor, 0], Opacity[0.2], Yellow, 
    MeshCells[vor, 2]}], PointSize[0.02], Point[pts[[1]]], Green, 
  MeshPrimitives[vor, 2][[1]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looking at the above, we see that the Voronoi sites (points that generate the Voronoi diagram) do not correspond to the Voronoi cells (in the order) generated by `VoronoiMesh`. Since `VoronoiMesh` discards the points used in generating the diagram, there's no obvious way I can see to align the Voronoi sites with their corresponding cells. This feels like an oversight to me, since one will have to do some complex post-processing to obtain such correspondence.

**My question is:** is there an easy way to obtain a site - cell alignment of the Voronoi diagram obtained via `VoronoiMesh` other than using e.g. `RegionMember` which seems like an unnecessary overkill when this information should be available in the `Mesh` object. So e.g. with the points above, an output of the form shown below is desirable:

```
Transpose[{pts, MeshCells[vor, 2]}]
```

> ```
> {{{3.15429516, 1.68154241}, Polygon[{20, 11, 6, 15}]}, 
>  {{0.925806386, 3.57266721}, Polygon[{12, 3, 1, 13}]}, 
>  {{2.12535296, 3.88158116}, Polygon[{14, 5, 8, 18}]},
>  {{3.52419343, 0.689832144}, Polygon[{18, 8, 7, 17}]},
>  {{0.590442758, 1.53821808}, Polygon[{10, 4, 9, 6, 11}]},
>  {{2.70632597, 3.81614775}, Polygon[{19, 13, 1, 5, 14}]},
>  {{2.23994147, 1.5141697}, Polygon[{15, 6, 9, 2, 16}]},
>  {{3.68657472, 2.93505855}, Polygon[{16, 2, 3, 12, 21}]},
>  {{0.12127097, 2.63380289}, Polygon[{17, 7, 4, 10, 22}]},
>  {{2.21266451, 2.69765978}, Polygon[{1, 3, 2, 9, 4, 7, 8, 5}]}}
> ```

Comment: Good question. I was sure that one of `vor["Properties"]` would hold the answer but no luck...

Comment: @SimonWoods Yeah, I thought so too. I was disappointed to find out it didn't.

Comment: @SimonWoods Maybe "PointInFaces" can give some information.But the order is strange identically.

Comment: In [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115940/a-unexpected-behaviour-of-relationgraph),I want to use `RelationGraph[RegionMember[#2, #1] &, pts, poly]` to make it.

Answer (score 21):

Of course it's not good that *Mathematica* forget initial points for Voronoi mesh. May be it is a bug. However one can easily recover all generating points directly from the mesh. It's interesting from theoretical point of view.

Let's consider one point of the Voronoi mesh

[image]

There are three pairs of equal angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ around this point. Therefore $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$. Hence we know
$$
\gamma = \pi-(\alpha+\beta)
$$
where $\alpha+\beta$ is an angle between known vectors ${\bf r}_1$ and ${\bf r}_2$. Then we can rotate ${\bf r}_3$ by angle $\gamma$ (to the left or the right) and obtain a ray to one of the generating points. Intersection of rays from different points will give the position of a generating point.

[image]

Here it is my realization of this method.

```
SeedRandom[0, Method -> {"MKL", Method -> {"Sobol", "Dimension" -> 2}}];
(* Voronoi cells looks better with sobol low-discrepancy random sequence *) 
pts = RandomReal[4, {50, 2}];
boundary = {{0, 4}, {0, 4}};
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, boundary];

q = MeshCoordinates[vor];
conn = # + #\[Transpose] &@
    SparseArray[# -> ConstantArray[1, Length@#], {1, 1} Max@#] &[# & @@@MeshCells[vor, 1]];
in = Flatten@Position[q, {x_, y_} /; 
     boundary[[1, 1]] < x < boundary[[1, 2]] && boundary[[2, 1]] < y < boundary[[2, 2]]];
(* points inside boundaries *)

g = Graphics@{GraphicsComplex[
MeshCoordinates@vor, {Thick, Blue, MeshCells[vor, 1], 
 PointSize@0.02, Red, MeshCells[vor, 0][[in]], Opacity@0.2, 
 Yellow, MeshCells[vor, 2]}], PointSize@0.02, Point@pts}
```

[image]

```
cells = MeshCells[vor, 2];
δ = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
e = {{0, -1}, {1, 0}};
c = e\[TensorProduct]δ - δ\[TensorProduct]e;
p1 = If[Length@# < 2, {}, LeastSquares@##] & @@ 
 Transpose@With[{pin = # ⋂ in, p = #}, 
   With[{a = c.(#4 - #).(#3 - #).(#2 - #)}, {a, a.#}] & @@@ 
    MapIndexed[q[[Join[pin[[#2]], # ⋂ p, #~Complement~p]]] &, 
     conn[[pin]]@"AdjacencyLists"]] & @@@ cells;
Show@{g, Graphics@{Orange, PointSize@0.02, Point@DeleteCases[p1, {}]}}
```

[image]

Inside the second `With` `#` is one of the not-boundary points in the Voronoi mesh. `#2` and `#3` is two neigbour points in the same polygon. `#4` is the neigbour point in another polygon. The matrix `c` make proper rotation to obtain a vector `a`, which is perpendicular to a ray.

Unfortunately there some generating points near edge, which we can not find by ray intersection (there are less then two rays). I mark these remain points by `{}` and denote by `rem`. We will find them by reflection of calculated points (denoted by `calc`).

```
rem = Flatten@Position[p1, {}];
calc = Complement[Range@Length@cells, rem];
edges = Partition[#, 2, 1, 1]~Join~Partition[Reverse@#, 2, 1, 1] & @@@ cells[[calc]];
p1[[rem]] = Mean /@ DeleteCases[
   If[p1[[calc]][[#]] != {}, 
       ReflectionTransform[Cross[Subtract @@ q[[edges[[##]]]]], 
         q[[edges[[##, 1]]]]]@p1[[calc]][[#]], {}] & @@@ 
   DeleteCases[Join @@ Position[edges, #] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1], {}] & @@@
  MeshCells[vor, 2][[Flatten@Position[p1, {}]]], {}];
Max@Abs[Sort@pts - Sort@p1]
```

We recover all points with high precision! Of course, the order of points is the same as in `MeshCells`.

> 3.9968*10^-15

[image]

Answer (score 21):

There is also a currently [undocumented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5940/145) internal function that may be useful.

`` Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[mr] `` generates a function which can be applied to list of points, giving for each `pt` the index of the (first encountered) highest-dimensional cell of `mr` containing `pt`. For example,

```
Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[vor][pts]

(* {{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 9}, {2, 1}, {2, 10}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {2, 6}} *)

pt = pts[[1]]; 
Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[vor], 
   {Thick, Blue, MeshCells[vor, 1], 
    PointSize[0.02], Red, MeshCells[vor, 0], 
    Opacity[0.2], Yellow, MeshCells[vor, 2]}], 
    PointSize[0.02], Magenta, Point[pt], 
    Opacity[0.2], Green, MeshPrimitives[vor, Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[vor][pt]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Having a correct correspondence between points and Voronoi cells (as actually quite strongly implied in the documentation) would be even better. Any chance there would be a fix for this? :I

Comment: @kirma I think it is a reasonable suggestion, but to my knowledge there is no guarantee of a particular ordering at present. Where/how exactly is it implied in the documentation?

Comment: Hmmh. Maybe I interpreted the second bullet point on "Details and Options" section of `VoronoiMesh` a bit too strongly. Correct ordering would make life a lot easier on many applications of `VoronoiMesh` nonetheless, and occassional non-ordering is a surprising feature to say the least.

Answer (score 15):

While I await other answers, here is the `RegionMember` approach I mentioned:

```
cellSite[p_, reg_] := With[{rm = RegionMember[reg]}, {Point@Flatten@Pick[p, rm[p]], reg}]
```

Then:

```
cs = cellSite[pts, #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vor, 2];
```

Visualize:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[vor], {Thick, Blue, MeshCells[vor, 1], 
 PointSize[0.02], Red, MeshCells[vor, 0], Opacity[0.2], Yellow, MeshCells[vor, 2]}], 
 PointSize[0.02], #1, Opacity[0.2], Green, #2, Red}] & @@@ cs, 5], ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I used a similar approach in [my implementation of the Lloyd algorithm](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97358).

Answer (score 13):

```
c = PropertyValue[{vor, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];
cents = Join @@ (Nearest @ pts /@c);
cs2 = Thread[{Point/@cents,MeshPrimitives[vor, 2]}];
cs2 == cs
(* True *)

Grid[Partition[Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[vor],
                            {Thick, Blue, MeshCells[vor, 1],
                            PointSize[0.02], Red, MeshCells[vor, 0], Opacity[0.2], 
                            Yellow, MeshCells[vor, 2]}],       
                         PointSize[0.02], #, Opacity[0.2],Green, #2, Red}] &@@@ cs2,5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't creating a `NearestFunction` be better? I still prefer `RegionMemberFunction` since it's listable.

Comment: @RunnyKine, agreed...

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution in my [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115940/a-unexpected-behaviour-of-relationgraph) but very slow

```
pts = RandomReal[4, {10, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}];
poly = MeshPrimitives[vor, 2];

AbsoluteTiming[
 youWant = 
  List @@@ EdgeList@Quiet[RelationGraph[RegionMember, poly, pts]]; 
 RegionMember @@@ youWant]
```

> {0.414993,{True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True}}

But I don't know why I get some error informations when I don't use `Quiet`.

---

Another more fast method can do this

```
youWant = Quiet[Gather[Join[pts, poly], # || RegionMember[#2, #] &]]
```