# Triangulated Mesh from Voronoi Diagram

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I want to generate a mesh (using *Mathematica* 10) in the following manner:
generate a Voronoi diagram, like so:

[image: Voronoi diagram]

and then triangulate each individual Voronoi grain, where an edge is formed by connecting each grain's corner to the "seed" point, like so (forgive my bad Photoshop skills):

[image: triangulated Voronoi diagram]

and then produce an adjacency list of the triangles contained within the triangulated mesh along with a list of the mesh points themselves. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a risk that I didn't understand what you want to do here but I'll try to answer your question to the best of my ability.

First we generate some random points and the corresponding voronoi mesh.

```
SeedRandom["LookAtThisSeed"]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {8, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

> [image]

We can use `MeshCoordinates` to get the vertex coordinates of the voronoi mesh. The following code generates a plot of the vertex labeling that we will be using for the rest of this answer.

```
ptsLabels = Text[#, pts[[#]], {-2, 0}] & /@ Range[Length@pts];
meshLabels = Text[# + Length@pts, MeshCoordinates[mesh][[#]], {-2, 0}] & /@ 
   Range[Length@MeshCoordinates[mesh]];

Show[mesh,
 ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Graphics[{Red, ptsLabels}],
 ListPlot[MeshCoordinates[mesh], PlotStyle -> Orange],
 Graphics[{Red, meshLabels}]
 ]
```

> [image]

It's easy to get the vertex coordinates of the voronoi mesh as we have seen and we can also get the vertex numbers of every voronoi cell separately with `MeshCells[mesh, 2]`. We don't know which seed belongs to which cell though. 
The following code provides the pts in the order in which `MeshCells[mesh, 2]` provides the corresponding voronoi cells.

```
testpoint[poly_, pt_] := Round[(Total@Mod[(# - RotateRight[#])
    &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)] != 0

vorCellOrdering = Table[Position[testpoint[
       MeshCoordinates[mesh][[#]] & /@ MeshCells[mesh, 2][[a, 1]], 
       pts[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length@pts], True][[1, 1]], {a, 1, 
   Length@MeshCells[mesh, 2]}]
```

> ```
> {5, 6, 8, 1, 7, 4, 2, 3}
> ```

Let's now define some `EdgeRules` for the graph we want to draw. `rules1` are the edges that define the voronoi cells while `rules2` are the edges that you drew red in your question.

```
rules1 = Flatten@
   Table[vorCellOrdering[[n]] <-> # + Length@pts & /@ 
     MeshCells[mesh, 2][[n, 1]], {n, 1, Length@pts}];
rules2 = EdgeList@SimpleGraph@Graph@Flatten[
      Thread[UndirectedEdge[# + Length@pts, 
            RotateLeft[# + Length@pts]]] &@
         MeshCells[mesh, 2][[#, 1]] & /@ Range[Length@pts]];
```

After some coordinate reordering we are ready to draw the desired graph.

```
vertexCoord = 
  Flatten[{pts, MeshCoordinates[mesh]}, 1][[#]] & /@ 
   VertexList@Graph[Flatten[{rules1, rules2}]];

g = HighlightGraph[
  Graph[Flatten[{rules1, rules2}], VertexCoordinates -> vertexCoord, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"], rules1]
```

> [image]

Now comes the tricky part for me. I didn't really get what you meant with

> [...] adjacency list of the triangles [...]

can you clarify that part?

The list of the triangle mesh points can be generated with

```
triangleVertices = Flatten[Table[Transpose[
    {ConstantArray[vorCellOrdering[[n]], 
        Length@MeshCells[mesh, 2][[n, 1]]], #, 
       RotateLeft[#]} &@(MeshCells[mesh, 2][[n, 1]] + 
       Length@pts)], {n, 1, Length@pts}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{5, 20, 14}, {5, 14, 12}, {5, 12, 19}, {5, 19, 20}, {6, 22, 9}, {6, 
>    9, 18}, {6, 18, 25}, {6, 25, 22}, {8, 21, 15}, {8, 15, 9}, {8, 9, 
>    22}, {8, 22, 21}, {1, 13, 10}, {1, 10, 11}, {1, 11, 12}, {1, 12, 
>    14}, {1, 14, 13}, {7, 26, 16}, {7, 16, 13}, {7, 13, 14}, {7, 14, 
>    20}, {7, 20, 26}, {4, 19, 12}, {4, 12, 11}, {4, 11, 17}, {4, 17, 
>    24}, {4, 24, 19}, {2, 18, 9}, {2, 9, 15}, {2, 15, 10}, {2, 10, 
>    13}, {2, 13, 16}, {2, 16, 18}, {3, 23, 17}, {3, 17, 11}, {3, 11, 
>    10}, {3, 10, 15}, {3, 15, 21}, {3, 21, 23}}
> ```

I'm sure I can improve some of the code if I find time tomorrow...

Answer (score 4):

I first made a Voronoi diagram. (version 10)

```
SeedRandom["LookAtThisSeed"]
pts = RandomReal[{-1,1},{10,2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
grid = MeshPrimitives[mesh,2];
fig = Show[
  {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick,Gray}],Opacity[0],grid}]},
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Red,Point[pts]}],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Medium],Blue,Point[MeshCoordinates@mesh]}]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And I made triangles like this.

```
pts2 = grid /. Polygon :> Sequence;
nearF = Nearest[RegionCentroid /@ grid];
pcnt = RegionCentroid /@ grid;
makeTriangle[a_, l_] := Prepend[#, a] & /@ l
poly = makeTriangle[#1, Partition[#2, 2, 1, 1]] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{pts,pts2[[Flatten[Position[pcnt, #[[1]]] & /@ nearF /@ pts]]]}];

Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Orange], Opacity[0], Polygon /@ poly}],fig]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 4):

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {8, 2}];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

[image]

Using a variation of [this method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58397/125) in a related Q/A to associate points and the Voronoi cells they belong:

```
vcells[p_, reg_] := With[{rm = RegionMember[reg]},
   Polygon[Join[Pick[p, rm[p]],#]]&/@Partition[Join[reg[[1]],{reg[[1,1]]}],2,1]];
mps=MeshPrimitives[vm, 2];
cs = vcells[pts, #] & /@mps;

i=1;Graphics[{{Opacity[.5],h=ColorData[63,"ColorList"][[i++]], JoinForm["Round"],
     EdgeForm[{Darker@h}],#}&/@cs,Opacity[1],Red,PointSize[.03],Point@pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I propose to add `JoinForm["Round"]` to the `EdgeForm`. P.S. `vm` instead of `mesh`.

Comment: @ybeltukov, thanks! I was trying to figure out how to fix those lines sticking out - `JoinForm` did not occure to me:)

Comment: @RunnyKine, sorry - Junho took `Nearest` first; and, I think, I did manage to make your nice/clean one-liner into an ugly beast:)

Comment: No worries, it looks fine. Plus the nice answer makes up for it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation of Junho's answer, using the *undocumented* function [`` Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[] ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109687):

```
SeedRandom["LookAtThisSeed"]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts];
id = Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[vm][pts][[All, 2]];
cells = MeshPrimitives[vm, 2][[id]];
tris = MapThread[Function[{pt, cell}, Map[Polygon[Prepend[#, pt]] &,
                 Partition[First[cell], 2, 1, 1]]], {pts, cells}];

Graphics[{FaceForm[], {EdgeForm[Orange], tris}, {EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Gray]], cells},
          AbsolutePointSize[5], {Red, Point[pts]}, {Blue, MeshPrimitives[vm, 0]}}]
```

[image: triangulated Voronoi cells]