# Lloyd relaxation on VoronoiMesh

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

How can we apply [Lloyd's relaxation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm#Algorithm_description) to a `VoronoiMesh`?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks a lot KennyColnago for your answer. Based on Simon Woods suggestion of using `PropertyValue[{vmesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid]`, I think this code can be simplified a bit, e.g.

```
VoronoiAdaptive2[p_, iter_] := Block[{vmesh = VoronoiMesh[p]},
Do[
vmesh = VoronoiMesh[PropertyValue[{vmesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid]],
{i, iter}];
vmesh];
```

Now I have a question about the algorithm itself: According to Wikipedia,

> Each time a relaxation step is performed, the points are left in a slightly more even distribution: closely spaced points move farther apart, and widely spaced points move closer together.

But using a large number of iterations with the above code results in a mesh with a concentration of very small cells in the center and large cells on the boundary (omitting the line of KennyColnago's code that excludes cells beyond a certain radius).

For example, with 200 points and the same random seed as KennyColnago and 200 iterations, the following mesh is produced:

```
SeedRandom[1729];
VoronoiAdaptive2[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {200, 2}], 200]
```

[image: 200 iters]

Going up to 1200 iterations produces a visually identical image. Is this the expected output? I was hoping to see something more like [on this website](https://www.jasondavies.com/lloyd/)

Comment: It would help potential answerers if you included some code to generate a `VoronoiMesh` to work with, and any progress you have made in solving the problem yourself. Did you try implementing the description of the algorithm in the linked Wikipedia article?

Comment: For a neat application (v10) of adaptive Voronoi meshes to images, see the Help page for VoronoiMesh > Applications > Image Processing. With iteration, the cells become nearly circular, and their sizes adapt locally to the image structure.

Comment: You might be interested in section 3 of [my post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/759091?p_p_auth=gyF67FTv) on the Wolfram Community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address the update to the question, you can use the second argument of `VoronoiMesh` to set a rectangular boundary which will let the algorithm converge to a uniform spacing. It looks like the linked animation is also inserting additional points at the centre, or perhaps it starts with a high density of points near the centre of the mesh. Here is something similar - I keep inserting a point at {0,0} until there are 200 points:

```
vmesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}]];
Dynamic[
 pts = PropertyValue[{vmesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];
 If[Length@pts < 200, AppendTo[pts, {0, 0}]];
 vmesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's my take on Lloyd's algorithm. The code I present here should not be too hard to encapsulate into a routine; I have only elected to present it in this way so that I can animate the progress of the relaxation method:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}]];

pl = With[{maxit = 50, (* maximum iterations *)
           tol = 0.005 (* distance tolerance *)}, 
          FixedPointList[Function[pts, Block[{cells},
                         cells = MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[pts,
                                                {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], "Faces"];
                         RegionCentroid /@ cells[[SparseArray[
                         Outer[#2 @ #1 &, pts, RegionMember /@ cells, 1],
                         Automatic, False]["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]]]]]],
                         pts, maxit, 
                         SameTest -> (Max[MapThread[EuclideanDistance,
                                                    {#1, #2}]] < tol &)]];

MapThread[Show, {VoronoiMesh /@ Rest[pl], 
                 MapThread[Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[3], Line[{##}],
                                    {Black, Point[#1]}, {Red, Point[#2]}}] &,
                           #] & /@ Partition[pl, 2, 1]}] // ListAnimate
```

[image: Lloyd relaxation]

Note: I elected not to use `PropertyValue[{(* mesh *), 2}, MeshCellCentroid]`, since the centroids are not returned in the same order as the points that generated their corresponding cells, thus necessitating a complicated termination criterion.

---

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109687), ilian shows an undocumented function that can be used to simplify the implementation of Lloyd's algorithm. Here's how it goes:

```
pl = With[{maxit = 50, (* maximum iterations *)
           tol = 0.005 (* distance tolerance *)}, 
          FixedPointList[Function[pts, Block[{cells, ci, vm},
                         vm = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
                         cells = MeshPrimitives[vm, "Faces"]; 
                         ci = Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[vm];
                         RegionCentroid /@ cells[[ci[pts][[All, -1]]]]]], pts, maxit, 
                         SameTest -> (Max[MapThread[EuclideanDistance,
                                                    {#1, #2}]] < tol &)]];
```

Comment: This is nice. Thanks for pointing me to this. I still think it's crazy there's no easy way to get corresponding cells for the sites.

Comment: It annoys me a lot that I had to complicate my implementation here because of this scrambling. Maybe if enough of us complain…

Answer (score 6):

The following imperfect code is what I play with. Given an input set of points `p`, run `VoronoiMesh` `iter` times, each time replacing the points with the centroids of the cells.

```
VoronoiAdaptive[p_, iter_] :=
   Block[{points = p, vmesh, coord, poly, centroids, 
          error = ConstantArray[0, iter]},
         vmesh = VoronoiMesh[points];
         coord = MeshCoordinates[vmesh];
         poly = MeshCells[vmesh, 2];
         centroids = Map[Mean[coord[[#[[1]]]]] &, poly];
         Do[
            points = centroids;
            vmesh = VoronoiMesh[points];
            coord = MeshCoordinates[vmesh];
            poly = MeshCells[vmesh, 2];
            centroids = Map[Mean[coord[[#[[1]]]]] &, poly];
            error[[i]] = Mean[Abs[Flatten[points - centroids]]],
            {i, 1, iter}];
         Print[error];
         {coord, poly}
   ]
```

Here is a plot of the original mesh for 200 random points. Cells with vertices outside an arbitrary radius of 1.5 are removed.

```
Block[{p, coord, poly, iter = 0},
   SeedRandom[1729];
   p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];
   {coord, poly} = VoronoiAdaptive[p, iter];
   poly = DeleteCases[poly, _?(Max[Map[Norm, coord[[#[[1]]]]]] > 1.5 &)];
   Graphics[{PointSize[0.02],
      EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.001], White}],
      GraphicsComplex[coord, poly],
      Red, Point[p],
      Frame -> True, Background -> Black]
]
```

[image: no iterations]

Setting `iter=10` gives the following.

[image: 10 iterations]

Comment: You could use `PropertyValue[{vmesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid]` to get the centroids

Comment: Thanks a lot, @KennyColnago. I'm wondering though why using a large number of iterations doesn't produce a very uniform mesh like in the animation [here](https://www.jasondavies.com/lloyd/).