# NearestMeshCells in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: geometry, mesh, lattices

Is there an efficient way of writing a function equivalent to `NearestMeshCells` (Mathematica 12.1) in Mathematica 11.3? I'm trying to write my own code, which I can share once I figure it out, but just wondered if someone already did something like this that could save me some time.

It would be enough for me to have the simplest functionality, that is,

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58395)?

Comment: To make J.M.'s link a bit more precise: [(109687)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109687).