# Extract original vertex from VoronoiMesh

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

Consider a set of random coordinates.

```
pts = SortBy[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}], {First, Last}];
```

and find it's `VoronoiMesh`,

```
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

[image]

Now for finding faces, we can use `mesh["Faces"]` to list  them base on the coordination of mesh vertices

```
pts2 = mesh["Coordinates"];
```

Which for example you can colored them as follows,

```
col = RandomColor[Length@pts];
Graphics[{{col, Polygon[pts2[[#]]] & /@ mesh["Faces"]}\[Transpose]}]
```

[image]

But I cannot find in `mesh["Properties"]` any entry related to original vertices, `pts.`
In other words, I want to relate faces (listed in `mesh["Faces"]` ) to original points (listed in `pts`)
For example, properties `"PointInFaces"` gives a point in each face, but it is not the original points,

[image]

I can use the following code to relate faces to original points, but it is a time-consuming task, particularly when the number of points is large.

```
VORfaces = Polygon[pts2[[#]]] & /@ mesh["Faces"];
Flatten@Position[# \[Element] VORfaces[[1]] & /@ pts,True] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Another suggestion is by using `PointInFaces` and `Nearest` function.

```
ff = Nearest[pts -> "Index"]
originalpointIndex =Flatten[ff /@ mesh["PointInFaces"]]
```

By potting them, you can find an excellent match,

```
Graphics[{{col, Polygon[pts2[[#]]] & /@ mesh["Faces"]}\[Transpose], Text[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ ({Range[Length@pts], pts}\[Transpose]), White, Text[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ ({originalpointIndex, mesh["PointInFaces"]}\[Transpose]) }]
```

[image]

I am wondering if there are any natural properties to relate mesh coordinate and original vertices?

Comment: seen [this answer by ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58570/125)?

Comment: Thank you, @kglr. No, I googled my question and I had not found this link. It is my answer anyhow.