# Boundary cells of a mesh?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, undocumented

This is an offspring of [answering another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134501/22013).

---

Consider

```
data = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1},
        {9.5, 14.9}, {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5},
        {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7},
        {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 3.1}, {11, 1.1}};

vor = VoronoiMesh[data];
```

All indices of the interior faces can be obtained with

```
i2 = MeshCellIndex[vor, {2, "Interior"}] (* undocumented *)
```

thence

```
HighlightMesh[vor, Style[i2, Red]]
```

[image]

It works also for points (`0`) and lines (`1`):

```
i0 = MeshCellIndex[vor, {0, "Interior"}]
i1 = MeshCellIndex[vor, {1, "Interior"}]
```

[image]

I found (by trial-and-error) that there's also `"Boundary"`:

```
b0 = MeshCellIndex[vor, {0, "Boundary"}]
b1 = MeshCellIndex[vor, {1, "Boundary"}]
```

giving

[image]

Unfortunately,

```
MeshCellIndex[vor, {2, "Boundary"}]
```

> {}

doesn't work.

**Questions:**

1. Is there something similar to `"Interior"` for the bordering faces (i.e., the missing `MeshCellIndex[vor, {2, "Boundary"}]` output)? They can be obtained with `Complement[MeshCellIndex[vor, 2], i2]`, but it looks too cumbersome compared to the `"Interior"` simplicity.
2. Regarding the lines (`1`), `"Interior"` and `"Boundary"` don't give all of them (i.e., the ones leading from the interior to the boundary); the remaining can be obtained with `Complement[MeshCellIndex[vor, 1], b1, i1]`, but again it would be nice to have a one-word description.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found by trial-and-error that `MeshCellIndex[vor,{2,"Frontier"}]` gives what you are looking for:

```
HighlightMesh[vor, Style[ MeshCellIndex[vor,{2,"Frontier"}], Red]]
```

or

```
MeshRegion[vor,  MeshCellStyle -> ({2,"Frontier"}->Red)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the lines *leading from the interior to the boundary* you can simply replace `2` above with `1`. For example,

```
MeshRegion[vor,  MeshCellStyle -> ({1,"Frontier"}->Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How to find those all *undocument string*?

Comment: @yode, just tried some of the properties returned by `vor["Properties"]`.