# Interior of discretized region

Tags: regions, mesh, finite-element-method

I have some domain of interest:

```
r = 0.3;
dom = ImplicitRegion[(x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 >= r^2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
```

Now I can extract mesh of the whole domain or just boundary:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Boundary = First@ToBoundaryMesh[dom];
Domain = First@ToElementMesh[dom];
```

If I `ListPlot` those two, Boundary is what I expected: All points that lie on the boundary of `dom`. However, can I somehow extract only the interior points of `dom`? That is, something like "Domain - Boundary"? Is there a function that does it in a nice way? I'm really interested only in pure positions of points, that's why I'm taking `First@` of the whole dataset.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[dom];

boundaryIncidents = Union@Flatten@ElementIncidents[mesh["BoundaryElements"]];
allIncidents = Union@Flatten@ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]];
interiorIncidents = Complement[allIncidents, boundaryIncidents];

allCoordinates = mesh["Coordinates"];
boundaryCoordinates = allCoordinates[[boundaryIncidents]];
interiorCoordinates = allCoordinates[[interiorIncidents]];

Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 Graphics[{
   PointSize[Large],
   Red, Point[boundaryCoordinates],
   Blue, Point[interiorCoordinates]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can think of incidents as the indices of coordinates in the list `mesh["Coordinates"]`. The idea is the same as that of `GraphicsComplex` if you have ever used that. `mesh["BoundaryElements"]` gives you all the line elements that make up the boundary described using incidents. `mesh["MeshElements"]` gives you all the triangles that make up the mesh described using the same incidents. All we have to do to get the coordinates that are not on the boundary is take the incidents of the full mesh and remove the incidents that are used in the boundary elements.

Here is another approach:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[dom, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
boundary = bmesh["Coordinates"];
interior = Complement[mesh["Coordinates"], boundary];
```

I specify `"MeshOrder"` just to make sure it will be the same in the mesh and the boundary mesh. I noticed that by default the boundary mesh gets mesh order 1 and the full mesh gets mesh order 2.

Another option, provided by user21:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[dom, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
coords = mesh["Coordinates"]; 
boundaryIDs = Flatten[ElementIncidents[mesh["PointElements"]]];
interiorIDs = Complement[Range[Length[coords]], boundaryIDs];
```

Comment: Thank you, the second solution is actually very short and elegant!

Comment: One more thing I would like to know...how can I write down the boundary normal vector facing towards the interior? I want to have it like list of {nx,ny}, but after you make those lists there is no way to reproduce it. Doesn't ElementMesh have something like that?

Comment: @user16320 Have you seen the `BoundaryNormals` property? It is documented in the `ElementMesh` documentation page.

Comment: Thank you, however I get the error "There is no method BoundaryNormals  for ElementMesh objects." even for the examples from the documentation page, so this option, I'm afraid, is of no use to me :(

Comment: @user16320 The examples work for me in Mathematica 11.2.

Comment: [This is what it shows.](http://imgur.com/a/JFfb2)

Comment: @C.E. 11.2 is it a beta? You pretty lucky... ;)

Comment: @PlatoManiac Yes, I am lucky. Although it was unintentional to reveal this here, my point is simply that it works.

Comment: Oh, I got it working. But I want to match the normal with the point on the boundary: by simply checking for size, First@bmesh is of a different size than the list of normals, thus it is not a one to one correspondence between points on the boundary and their corresponding normals (not to mention that the normals are oriented differently on the outer boundary than on the inner one - I expect all of them to be oriented either towards the domain, or the other way around, but not mixed).

Comment: Never mind, I somehow managed it by setting MeshOrder back to 1, fiddling with MaxCellMeasure and adding SameTest to the Complement function you used.

Comment: @user16320 Yes, I was going to say that `BoundaryNormals` always uses mesh order 1.

Comment: You could also use `mesh = ToElementMesh[dom, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
boundaryIDs = Flatten[ElementIncidents[mesh["PointElements"]]];
interiorIDs = Complement[Range[Length[coords]], boundaryIDs];` also note that "BoundaryNormals" is part of 11.1 and documented on the `ElementMesh` ref page.

Answer (score 8):

Look [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134625/boundary-cells-of-a-mesh)

```
region = DiscretizeRegion[dom];
Show[region, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.02], 
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[dom], {0, "Interior"}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Using mesh region functions:

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[dom];
boundary = RegionBoundary[reg];
coords = MeshCoordinates[reg];

pointindex = 
  Pick[Range[Length[coords]], RegionMember[boundary, coords], False];

MeshRegion[reg, MeshCellStyle -> {{0, pointindex} -> Red}]
```

[image]

If you want to get coordinates of interior points:

```
coords[[pointindex]]
```

or you can do from beginning:

```
Pick[coords, RegionMember[boundary, coords], False]
```