# Picking mesh elements that are not on the border of the mesh

Tags: performance-tuning, mesh

As an example, let's say I use a set of random points to create a Voronoi mesh

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
VoronoiMesh[pts, {-1, 1}]
```

and get something that looks like this:

[image]

My question is: Is there an efficient way to determine which of the regions (mesh elements, whatever you call them) are not touching the edge of the mesh? I know that there are a lot of built in functions that give properties of elements in a mesh, but I am unfamiliar with them, and I can't seem to find an efficient way to do this beyond "looping" through all elements and just picking which elements do not have points that touch the edge.

Comment: [`RegionBoundary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBoundary.html)? To get coordinates you can do ``RegionBoundary@mesh // MeshCoordinates``

Comment: @b3m2a1 I mean to find the "shapes" that are not touching the outside. I don't need the coordinates of the outer edge.

Comment: Ah I did a lazy read through and figured you wanted the boundary. Always possible to take a complement with the boundary cells, though, to get the interior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts, {-1, 1}]
HighlightMesh[vm, MeshCellIndex[vm, {2, "Interior"}]]
```

[image]

Related: [Boundary cells of a mesh?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134634/125)

```
Show[vm, Epilog -> {Opacity[.7, Orange], MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yep that was the simple answer I was expecting haha. Thanks!

Comment: @kglr Wow, I'm impressed. Where did you find this syntax? The doc page of `MeshCellIndex` does not show it as example...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, blind search trying some objects returned by `vm["Properties"]`:)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Exactly what I was thinking! I'll definitely look at those properties though and see if there are other useful things.

Answer (score 8):

For planar `MeshRegion` that arise from `DelaunayMesh` or `VoronoiMesh`, usually

```
R["InteriorFaces"]
```

should work.

A more general and more transparent ways is to use the package [`` "IGraphM`" ``](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) by Szabolcs as follows:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

A = IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 1, 2];
bndedges = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Total[A, {2}], 1];
interiorfaces = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Total[A[[bndedges]]], 0];

HighlightMesh[R, Thread[{2, interiorfaces}]]
```

[image]