# Creating a Hexagonal Lattice with VoronoiMesh

Tags: mesh, style, lattices

I want to create a hexagonal lattice using `VoronoiMesh`. One can achieve that with the following code, where `L=5`,

```
pts = Flatten[
   Table[{3/2 i, Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, L}, {j, L}], 1];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

[image]

Changing the code slightly, I can delete the overly sized cells in the following manner

```
pts = Flatten[
   Table[{3/2 i, Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, L + 2}, {j, 
     L + 2}], 1];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh], 
 With[{a = PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
  With[{m = 3}, Pick[MeshCells[mesh, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]]
```

to get

[image]

Now, I want to add a bit of "realism" to the mesh, by including a noise term in each coordinate of the cell centroids.

```
rt = 0.5;
pts = Flatten[
   Table[{3/2 i + RandomReal[rt], 
     Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2 + RandomReal[rt]}, {i, 
     L + 2}, {j, L + 2}], 1];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh], 
 With[{a = PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
  With[{m = 3}, Pick[MeshCells[mesh, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]]
```

[image]

As one can see, the `MeshCellMeasure` threshold fails in this case, and I get either holes in the mesh or those "pointy" cells that I have previously excluded. How do I solve this?

I thought about tracking the specific boundary cells and delete them from the Voronoi mesh. Is this viable? How could I do that?

Comment: I'd consider the opposite route: start with a mesh on random points extracted from a region with the rough shape you want (see `RandomPoint`), and carry out enough rounds of [Lloyd relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm#Algorithm_description) on the resulting mesh to get it "regular enough". Should you go this route, you can find excellent code ready to go in [Lloyd relaxation on `VoronoiMesh`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96087/27951). You should then be able to use your own code to remove the "borders".

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189009/38178) might be helpful to extract the interior cells.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is what I was suggesting in comments:

```
SeedRandom[]

relaxed = Nest[
   PropertyValue[{VoronoiMesh[#, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {2, All}}, MeshCellCentroid] &,
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {45, 2}],
   500
];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[relaxed, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> White}];
```

[image: relaxed quasi-hexagonal lattice]

Then extract the cell primitives corresponding to the interior cells and generate a new `Mesh` object:

```
interiorMesh = MeshRegion[
   MeshCoordinates[mesh],
   MeshCells[mesh, {2, "Interior"}],
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> White}
 ]
```

[image: new mesh comprising only the interior cells from the previous Mesh]

---

Depending on whether the application focuses on visualization or further computation, one could prefer having the output as simple `Graphics` objects instead, which are far easier to style than mesh components, at least for me:

```
Graphics[{
  Darker@Green, EdgeForm[{Thick, White}], 
  MeshPrimitives[mesh, {2, "Interior"}]
}]
```

[image: Graphics output for the same selection]

Comment: Just one question. Would it be possible to specify the number of interior cells to display? I'm finding it difficult since it will depend on the number of boundary cells, which can vary in each simulation. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Also, is it possible to avoid `Graphics`? That is, can I select the interior cells using the `MeshPrimitives` and still get a mesh-type object? I ask this because I intend to use `SetProperty` later, and I can't do that to a `Graphics`-type object.

Comment: @Sam For your first question (how many cells to display), I don't see a way to force that, since the number of interior cells depends on the shape of the mesh; perhaps starting from a non-random mesh could do. Let me think about that.

Comment: @Sam for your second question, I added an approach that returns a `Mesh`.

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

If you are not completely attached to Voronoi, you might consider tiling with hexagons and then perturbing their coordinates. `GraphicsComplex` makes it work.

Define a hexagon.

```
HexTile[s_] := Polygon[s*{{Sqrt[3], 1}/2, {0, 1}, {-Sqrt[3], 1}/2,
                          {-Sqrt[3], -1}/2, {0, -1}, {Sqrt[3], -1}/2}]
```

Allow for translation.

```
TranslateObject[p_, {x_, y_}] := Map[{x, y} + # &, p, {2}]
```

Make a grid of hexagons.

```
HexGrid[s_, h_, v_] :=
   Flatten[Table[
      TranslateObject[HexTile[s], s {i*Sqrt[3] + Mod[j, 2]*Sqrt[3]/2, 3 j/2}],
      {i, 0, h}, {j, 0, v}], 1]
```

Make a perturbed grid of hexagons.

```
HexGridPerturbed[s_, h_, v_, r_] := 
   Block[{poly = Map[Round[#, 10.^-10] &, HexGrid[N[s], h, v], {2}], p, m, rules},
      p = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[poly[[All, 1]], 1]];
      m = Length[p];
      rules = Dispatch[Thread[p -> Range[m]]];
      GraphicsComplex[
         p + RandomReal[{-r, r}, {m, 2}],
         poly /. rules]
   ]
```

Manipulate

```
Manipulate[
   Graphics[{
      EdgeForm[{Thick, White}],
      HexGridPerturbed[s, h, v, r]}],
   {{s, 1, "Hexagon Size"}, 0.1, 3., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{h, 5, "Horizontal Count"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{v, 3, "Vertical Count"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   {{r, 0., "Random Noise"}, 0., 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image: perturbed hexagonal grid]

**Comment:**

With this code, I was able to make a 3D impression saving the result of the code in a file with the extension STL.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed today. I don't even have to look any further

Comment: You actually 3d printed it ? That's real commitment right there.

Comment: Yes. I really printed in 3D. This is my hand holding a piece made from the code above. I exported to the SVG extension, worked on the file in the InkScape software, exported again to the DXF extension and worked on the Blender software to finally generate the STL file ...

Comment: This is my channel on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnBvTLPG9M1dbqA-sxN3UmA

Answer (score 10):

```
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]; 
hexagons = Select[Length[#[[1]]] == 6 &] @ MeshPrimitives[mesh, {2, "Interior"}]; 

DiscretizeGraphics @ Graphics @ hexagons
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
rt = 0.5;
pts = Flatten[Table[{3/2 i + RandomReal[rt], 
  Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2 + RandomReal[rt]}, {i, L + 2}, {j, L + 2}], 1];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];

hexagons = Select[Length[#[[1]]] == 6 &] @ MeshPrimitives[mesh, {2, "Interior"}]; 
DiscretizeGraphics @ Graphics @ hexagons
```

[image]