# Selecting Edges and Corners in a Mesh

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, mesh, style, lattices

Consider the following VoronoiMesh obtained after a few iterations of Lloyd's relaxation algorithm

```
L1 = 6; L2 = 10;
relaxed = 
  Nest[PropertyValue[{VoronoiMesh[#, {{-1, L2 + 2}, {-1, 
         L1 + 2}}], {2, All}}, 
     MeshCellCentroid] &, {RandomReal[L2 + 2, (L1 + 2) (L2 + 2)], 
     RandomReal[L1 + 2, (L1 + 2) (L2 + 2)]} // Transpose, 200];
mesh0 = VoronoiMesh[relaxed]
```

[image]

Now, inspired by the discussion in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212624/creating-a-hexagonal-lattice-with-voronoimesh), I can first pick the "nicely shaped" interior cells, based on the cell area

```
mesh1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh0], 
  With[{a = PropertyValue[{mesh0, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
   With[{m = 1.5}, Pick[MeshCells[mesh0, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]]
```

[image]

My goal is now to be able to easily manage the boundary (edges and corners independently) and interior, including/removing them in a "toggleable" way. This would define 9 regions in total (4 corners, 4 edges and 1 interior region). I'm already able to select either the boundary or the interior, as can be seen here

```
MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh1], MeshCells[mesh1, {2, "Frontier"}]]
```

[image]

and

```
MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh1], MeshCells[mesh1, {2, "Interior"}]]
```

[image]

Is there a good way to detect edges and/or corners of meshes like this? I'm aware of commands like `IntersectingQ` and `Pick`, that could prove to be useful. Any ideas?

**Edit:** For example, I would like to obtain meshes like the following (with the interior also "toggable")

[image]

Also, by edges I mean any of the four cell arrays that constitute the frontier/boundary of the mesh. Corners might be trickier to uniquely define, given that the mesh is slightly perturbed, but a solution for the edges would be great nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can identify the four corners by finding the coordinates of bounding rectangle of `mesh1`

```
cbounds = Tuples @ RegionBounds[mesh1];
```

and using the function `` Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex ``

```
fourcorners = Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[mesh1] /@ cbounds]
```

To partition the frontier faces into 8 parts (four corners and four edges) we need to do some sorting:

```
ClearAll[sortCounterClockwise]
sortCounterClockwise = SortBy[#2, 
    Function[x, ArcTan @@ (PropertyValue[{#, x}, MeshCellCentroid] - RegionCentroid[#])]] &;

sortedCorners = sortCounterClockwise[mesh1, fourcorners];

interiorCells = MeshCellIndex[mesh1, {2, "Interior"}];

sortedFrontier = sortCounterClockwise[mesh1, MeshCellIndex[mesh1, {2, "Frontier"}]];

sortedFrontier = RotateLeft[sortedFrontier, 
   -1 + Flatten[Position[sortedFrontier, First @ sortedCorners]]];

ClearAll[cornerCells, edgeCells]
Evaluate[Riffle[Array[cornerCells, 4], Array[edgeCells, 4]]] = 
  TakeList[sortedFrontier, 
   Riffle[-1 + Differences@ 
    Append[Flatten[Position[sortedFrontier, #] & /@ sortedCorners], 
       1 + Length@sortedFrontier], 1, {1, -2, 2}]];
```

Style each corner and edge with a different color and add legend:

```
cornerColors = {Red, Blue, Green, Cyan};
edgeColors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[4];

legend = SwatchLegend[Join[cornerColors, edgeColors, {LightBlue}], 
   Join[Subscript["corner", #] & /@ Range[4], 
     Subscript["edge", #] & /@ Range[4], {"interior"}], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}];


Legended[HighlightMesh[mesh1, 
  Join[MapThread[Style, {cornerCells /@ Range[4], cornerColors}], 
   MapThread[Style, {edgeCells /@ Range[4], edgeColors}], 
   {Style[interiorCells, LightBlue]}], 
 ImageSize -> Large], 
 Placed[legend, Right]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Use `FlipView` to toggle visibility of face groups:

```
ClearAll[fliP]
fliP = FlipView[{Style[#, #2], Style[#, Opacity[0]]}] &; 

cornerPrims = MeshPrimitives[mesh1, #] & /@ cornerCells /@ Range[4];
edgePrims = MeshPrimitives[mesh1, #] & /@ edgeCells /@ Range[4];
interiorPrims = MeshPrimitives[mesh1, #] & /@ interiorCells;

Graphics[Join[MapThread[fliP, {cornerPrims, cornerColors}], 
   MapThread[fliP, {edgePrims, edgeColors}],
   {fliP[interiorPrims, LightBlue]}],
   ImageSize -> Large] // Deploy
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`ToBoundaryMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html) to extract the points and edges like so:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
L1 = 6; L2 = 10;
relaxed = 
  Nest[PropertyValue[{VoronoiMesh[#, {{-1, L2 + 2}, {-1, 
         L1 + 2}}], {2, All}}, 
     MeshCellCentroid] &, {RandomReal[L2 + 2, (L1 + 2) (L2 + 2)], 
     RandomReal[L1 + 2, (L1 + 2) (L2 + 2)]} // Transpose, 200];
mesh0 = VoronoiMesh[relaxed]
mesh1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh0], 
  With[{a = PropertyValue[{mesh0, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
   With[{m = 1.5}, Pick[MeshCells[mesh0, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]]
mr1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh1], 
  MeshCells[mesh1, {2, "Frontier"}]]
mr2 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh1], 
  MeshCells[mesh1, {2, "Interior"}]]
(b0 = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary[mesh1], 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1])["Wireframe"]
(b1 = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary[mr1], 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1])["Wireframe"]
(b2 = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary[mr2], 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1])["Wireframe"]
lp1 = ListPlot[{b0["Coordinates"], b2["Coordinates"]}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Outer", "Inner"}]
fc0 = Flatten@
    FindCycle@Graph[ElementIncidents[b0["BoundaryElements"]][[1]]] /. 
   UndirectedEdge -> List;
fc2 = Flatten@
    FindCycle@Graph[ElementIncidents[b2["BoundaryElements"]][[1]]] /. 
   UndirectedEdge -> List;
Graphics[{Red, GraphicsComplex[b0["Coordinates"], Line[fc0]], Blue, 
  GraphicsComplex[b2["Coordinates"], Line[fc2]]}]
```

[image: Extract Points and Edges]

## Update Due To Confusion About Edges

When the term "edges" was used, I presumed that the 1d edges were desired to be extracted. The OP was edited with a new clarified definition.  The following approach might be helpful.

First, I extracted the connectivity from the polygons to construct a graph and then used  [`VertexDegree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexDegree.html) to find the nodes with the highest degree of sharing.

```
mc1 = MeshCells[mr1, 2];
conn = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[mr1, 2];
edges = MapThread[List, {#, RotateLeft[#]}] & /@ conn;
g = Graph[Flatten[edges, 1]];
HighlightVertexDegree[g_, vd_] := 
  HighlightGraph[g, 
   Table[Style[VertexList[g][[i]], 
     ColorData["TemperatureMap"][vd[[i]]/Max[vd]]], {i, 
     VertexCount[g]}]];
vd = VertexDegree[g];
HighlightVertexDegree[g, vd]
```

[image: Vertex Degree]

In my case, `VertexDegree` identified three corner point that had a high degree of sharing with other Polygons.

The following code extracts the high degree vertices and finds the polygons containing those vertices.  Those polygons are the corners and the complement are the "edges".

```
threenodes = Flatten@Position[vd, n_ /; n > 4];
cas = ContainsAny[#] & /@ conn;
polyswiththree = Through[cas[{#}]] & /@ threenodes;
notpolyswiththree = Map[Not, polyswiththree, 2] /. Not -> Identity;
poly = Pick[mc1, #] & /@ polyswiththree;
notpoly = Pick[mc1, #] & /@ notpolyswiththree;
Graphics[{Blue, 
  GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[mr1], 
   Complement[Flatten@Union@notpoly, Flatten@poly]]}]
Graphics[MapIndexed[{Hue[#2/4], 
    GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[mr1], #1]} &, poly]]
```

[image: Edges and Corners]

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm not entirely following your construction. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I've edited my question to exemplify the sort of meshes I'm looking for. Please take a look.

Comment: I was thinking of "edges" in the typical 1d sense found in FEM, so it is different from the way you are thinking edges.  I will keep my answer up for a while in case I think of anything, but I may delete it.

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you are doing. I will clarify the definition I'm using. Nonetheless, this is indeed a very neat construction, could be very useful for me later, but please do as you like.

Comment: I updated the post with my understanding of edges and corners.  Perhaps it is helpful.  There are probably more streamlined approaches, but it seems to work.