# A Smooth and Round Voronoi Mesh

Tags: graphics, regions, mesh, style, polygons

I want the edges of a `VoronoiMesh` to be smooth and round. I have found the following code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111690/64001)

```
arcgen[{p1_, p2_, p3_}, r_, n_] := 
 Module[{dc = Normalize[p1 - p2] + Normalize[p3 - p2], cc, th}, 
  cc = p2 + r dc/EuclideanDistance[dc, Projection[dc, p1 - p2]];
  th = Sign[
     Det[PadRight[{p1, p2, p3}, {3, 3}, 1]]] (π - 
       VectorAngle[p3 - p2, p1 - p2])/(n - 1);
  NestList[RotationTransform[th, cc], 
   p2 + Projection[cc - p2, p1 - p2], n - 1]]
roundedPolygon[Polygon[pts_?MatrixQ], r_?NumericQ, 
  n : (_Integer?Positive) : 12] := 
 Polygon[Flatten[
   arcgen[#, r, n] & /@ 
    Partition[If[TrueQ[First[pts] == Last[pts]], Most, Identity][pts],
      3, 1, {2, -2}], 1]]
```

Consider for example, the 3x3 hexagonal mesh (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212624/creating-a-hexagonal-lattice-with-voronoimesh) for more details)

```
L1 = 3; L2 = 3;
pts = Flatten[
   Table[{3/2 i, Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, L2 + 4}, {j, 
     L1 + 4}], 1];
mesh0 = VoronoiMesh[pts];
mesh1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh0], 
   With[{a = PropertyValue[{mesh0, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
    With[{m = 3}, Pick[MeshCells[mesh0, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]];
mesh = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh1], 
  MeshCells[mesh1, {2, "Interior"}]]
```

[image]

Using `roundedPolygon` defined above, I can get what I want with

```
Graphics[{Directive[LightBlue, EdgeForm[Gray], EdgeThickness -> .001], 
    roundedPolygon[#, 0.3]} & /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]]
```

[image]

This looks good already, but I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to fill the gaps between cells automatically? I first thought about setting a `Background` colour on in `Graphics` that would match the edge colour. This, however, yields a box look that I want to avoid. I could also change the edge thickness, but this doesn't seem to scale with the lattice size. Any idea how to solve this? The following picture illustrates these cases.

[image]

2. Is it possible to scale the `EdgeThickness` with the mesh size?
3. When I consider a square mesh, given, for example, by `pts = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, L2 + 2}, {j, L1 + 2}], 1]` and `mesh = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh0], 
      MeshCells[mesh0, {2, "Interior"}]]`

[image]

`roundedPolygon` seems to fail, returning, among others, the error

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

4. Finally, I wonder if it's possible to display the mesh as a mesh-type object and avoid using `Graphics`.

I don't expect to get an answer to everything, but any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

**Edit:** The answer to the main problem was already given. However, going a step further, I'm having some troubles using Chip Hurst's code below when considering a random `VoronoiMesh`. First, it seems that the way `diff` and `joints` are defined becomes problematic when considering such type of mesh, different types of errors appear. Furthermore, simply computing the rounded mesh (without filling the spaces), and setting

```
pts = {RandomReal[L2, L1 L2], RandomReal[L1, L1 L2]} // Transpose;
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

doesn't always yield what I expect from the `roundedPolygon` option. Occasionaly I get the right rounded mesh

[image]

But most times I get wrongly placed polygons

[image]

This seems to be an ordering problem, possibly from using `Nearest`, though I'm not sure. Using `Graphics` seems to work well with random meshes, but I'd like to be able to work with meshes. Filling the gaps in the random case might get really tricky, but everything works well with either regular square and hexagonal lattices, just wondering if we could go a step further. Any ideas?

Comment: What about putting just a colored disk with appropriate radius under each interior vertex of the grid? Or you put a copy of your grid with increased `EdgeForm[Thickness[whateveryouwant]` below.

Comment: Good idea! I think that is more or less what @kglr is doing below. Just wondering how I should set the correct scaling of their radii, depending on the mesh dimensions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 1 + 4

We can discretize the rounded `Polygon` objects and then add the negative of the mesh through `Prolog`.

```
rm = DiscretizeGraphics[roundedPolygon[#, 0.3] & /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]]
```

[image]

Now there's some floating point differences in the results from `roundedPolygon` that seem to effect subsequent Boolean operations. We can fix this crudely merging nearby points.

```
coordsnew = Mean /@ Nearest[MeshCoordinates[rm], MeshCoordinates[rm], {All, 10^-12.}];
rm = MeshRegion[coordsnew, MeshCells[rm, 2]];
```

Now find the difference:

```
diff = BoundaryMesh @ RegionDifference[
  Cuboid @@ Transpose[CoordinateBounds[MeshCoordinates[rm], Scaled[.05]]], rm]
```

[image]

And assemble:

```
joints = With[{comps = ConnectedMeshComponents[diff]},
   If[Length[comps] == 1,
    {},
    Show[
      BoundaryMeshRegion[
       RegionUnion[Rest[SortBy[comps, RegionBounds]]], 
       MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> GrayLevel[.3]}]
    ][[1]]
   ]
 ];

MeshRegion[
  rm, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Thick, GrayLevel[.3]}, 2 -> LightBlue}, 
  Prolog -> joints
]
```

[image]

## 3

It seems `roundedPolygon` is effected by an unnecessary run of consecutive duplicate points. We can fix this by deleting them.

```
roundedPolygon[p:Polygon[_?MatrixQ], zero_?PossibleZeroQ, ___] := p

roundedPolygon[Polygon[opts_?MatrixQ], r_?Positive, n : (_Integer?Positive) : 12] := 
  With[{pts = Split[opts][[All, 1]]},
    Polygon[Flatten[arcgen[#, r, n] & /@ 
     Partition[
      If[TrueQ[First[pts] == Last[pts]], Most, Identity][pts], 
      3, 1, {2, -2}
     ], 1]]
  ]
```

---

### Edit

We can use [`MeshCellShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellShapeFunction.html) to preserve the data in the original mesh while having custom rounded cells:

```
meshsty = MeshRegion[
  mesh, 
  MeshCellShapeFunction -> {2 -> (roundedPolygon[Polygon[#], 0.3]&)}, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Thick, GrayLevel[.3]}, 2 -> LightBlue}, 
  Epilog -> joints
]
```

[image]

Notice that this only the visualization is affected and not the underlying data:

```
RegionEqual[mesh, meshsty]
```

> True

Whereas the original solution does change the underlying data:

```
RegionEqual[mesh, rm]
```

> False

Comment: See my edit. ${}$

Comment: Thank you! This is great.

Comment: Sorry, just one more thing. I'm still getting the same error when `r==0`. It would be nice to have this option and get the "unrounded" mesh for r=0.

Comment: See my edit. I think this does what you want. Make sure to run `Clear[roundedPolygon]` beforehand.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to.

Comment: What command are running?

Comment: The problem seems to be in using `rm = DiscretizeGraphics[
   roundedPolygon[#, 0] & /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]];`

Comment: I'm running your code as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103491/discussion-between-chip-hurst-and-sam-wolfe).

Comment: If I consider a random `VoronoiMesh`, for the points `pts = {RandomReal[L2, L1 L2], RandomReal[L1, L1 L2]} // Transpose;` it's not always possible to get the intended smooth corners. Any way to fix this? Please see edit. In any case, thanks a lot, your answer is already great!

Comment: Chip, thanks for fixing my routine; I certainly did not design it for the case where there are repeated points between the first and last one. @sam, "it's not always possible to get the intended smooth corners" - for a sufficiently small polygon, you also need a sufficiently small rounding radius (second argument of `roundedPolygon[]`), and I did not provide for an automatic cutoff. You could use `Manipulate[]` to help explore a good rounding radius value, and then process tiny polygons (perhaps filtered by area or perimeter?) separately.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I think the automatic cutoff might be a good solution, but I would be happy if I could simply cut the extra bits off. If you can, please take a look a this follow-up question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215762/rounding-an-irregular-polygon

Comment: @samwolfe see my latest edit. It provides a way to change the display of a mesh without changing its underlying data.

Answer (score 9):

1. ***fill the gaps between cells***

```
Graphics[{PointSize[1 / L2 / 3], Red, MeshPrimitives[mesh, {0, "Interior"}], 
  {Directive[LightBlue, EdgeForm[Gray], EdgeThickness -> .001], 
    roundedPolygon[#, 0.3]} & /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: For bigger mesh sizes (`L1=L2=20`, for example), the `AbsolutePointSize` value is too big and the dots overflow the mesh. So maybe should value should scale with `L1` and `L2`. What would be the best way to do this? Maybe the same reasoning could be extended to the `EdgeThickness` (question 2).

Comment: @samwolfe, changing  `AbsolutePointSize[30]` to `PointSize[1/L2/3]` seems to work.