# Selecting Shared Edges from a Mesh

Tags: regions, filtering, mesh, intersection, lattices

Consider the following mesh

```
mesh0 = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {50, 2}]]
```

[image]

I can select interior polygons with

```
mesh = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh0], MeshCells[mesh0, {2, "Interior"}]]
```

[image]

My goal is to select only the edges that share a polygon. `MeshPrimitives` gets me close

```
Graphics[MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1]]
```

[image]

Now I would just need to select the edges from `MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1]` that share a polygon, in order to get something like

[image]

I know about `"Frontier"` as an option for `MeshCells`, but not entirely sure if I could use it. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is "Interior" and "Frontier" documented?

Comment: I don't know. Might be undocumented.

Comment: Where did you learn about them? Can you give me a link?

Comment: I believe the first time I learned about them was on MarcoB's answer on my question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212625/64001

Comment: Also, `BoundaryMesh` might do the trick. I'm trying.

Comment: I believe I solved, see below. Any improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, I have figured out an answer. The code

```
Complement[MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1], MeshPrimitives[BoundaryMesh[mesh], 1]] // Graphics
```

yields

[image]

which is what I want. Any comments/improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

With the syntax that you brought up yourself:

```
edges = Complement[
   MeshCells[mesh, {1}, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]],
   MeshCells[mesh, {1, "Boundary"}, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]
   ];
primitives = Partition[MeshCoordinates[mesh][[Flatten[edges]]], 2];
```

But also

```
edges= Union[
 MeshCells[mesh, {1, "Frontier"}, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]],
 MeshCells[mesh, {1, "Interior"}, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]
 ]
```

looks good.